# C# WinForms events not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title suggests, I cannot get a single event to fire from an MDIChild application. No mouse event, no load, keypress, nothing at all.

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {Console.WriteLine("Clicked");}

this.btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSave_Click);
```

Selected the event from the properties window, manually subscribed to the event and yet nothing at all.

Comment: Do you even put something in the EventHandler?

Comment: I honestly think that you need to show more than one line of code..also what happens if you double click on the `btnSave` in the form ..it should generate automatically an event for you try testing some code that way..

Comment: Yes but it's not even auto generating

Comment: Check the output window in the VS. Nothing will appear on the form if you use `Console.WriteLine` in winforms. (Unless you do some special things to implement such behaviour.)

Comment: Try putting btnSave.Visible = false; inside your event, see if your button disappears. It's a more visual way of testing if it even fires.

Comment: Good day to learn how the debugger insert breakpoint works.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest you could insert a break point to see if these events are being fired.

From the information in your question it looks like the issue is that you're calling

```
Console.WriteLine
```

From a Winforms application.If you want to see somethng appear you could try

```
MessageBox.Show("Clicked")
```

Console applications would show Console.WriteLine, but the fact that you have buttons suggests a WinForms app.

Comment: Console.WriteLIne works to show messages in the Output. Using the breakpoints found the problem.. the source was different from original which is an error I've never got but cleaning the solution and rebuilding fixed it. thanks